# Why is my sqlite database not persisting in cordova?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have a very basic create db statement like this:

```
  var instance = openDatabase(databaseModel.name, databaseModel.version, databaseModel.alias, databaseModel.timeout); //Open a DB based on Name and Version Number

 insertTable: function(insertStatement, dataArray) {
            var deferred = q.defer();
            try {
                var request = _db.instance.transaction(function(tx) { tx.executeSql(insertStatement, dataArray); });
                deferred.resolve(request);
            } catch (e) {
                deferred.reject(new Error(e));
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
```

This works great for opening a database and adding some records but when I close the browser or the Cordova app, the database is gone.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Could it be that because you did not define any success and error callback-handler for tx.executeSql function the entries actually were not saved in the DB because of a possible SQl-syntax-error? Either way there is some code missing.

Comment: Could you post the statements you are currently using and how did you know the database is gone?